# How to make reverse query of "array-contains" [firestore]

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have array of user IDs in my firestore collection.
I want to make query in Node js to get every document that does not include some specific id

```
db.collection("freeMusic").where("userIds", "array-contains", "ABB56WnLNWdbWNTyItrRiQyfgCU2")
      .get()
```

This is how I can get in which document there is specific user ID in array `userIds` but how can I do in reverse?

How to query every document that doesn't include specific value in array?

NOTE: This array of userIds can have big length even more than 100

Comment: How about `where("userIds", "not-in",[ "ABB56WnLNWdbWNTyItrRiQyfgCU2"])?`

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with multiple where condtions in one query?

Comment: You can try this: `var ref= db.collection("freeMusic"); ref.where("userIds", "not-in",[ "ABB56WnLNWdbWNTyItrRiQyfgCU2"]); ref=ref.where("userIds", "not-in",[ "xkk"]);
ref=ref.where ... ; ref.get();`

Comment: Even with your answer not-in I'm getting only one which contains that userID where query `.where("answeredUids", "not-in", ["ZBZ53WnLNWdbWNTyIekRiQyhoCK2"]);` and result  `"answeredUids": [
        "ZBZ53WnLNWdbWNTyIekRiQyhoCK2"
      ]`

Comment: I linked two questions to yours. In one Doug explains why this sort of query isn't possible on Firestore (it always goes back to it being able to meet its performance guarantee). In the other Jay explains a data model that might work for your use-case too.